# Node.js Module Function are not exported after ubuntu 16 upgrade from 14

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I currently upgraded from Ubuntu 14 LTS to 16 while using node.js as server i have a wrapper class that does all transaction to my table in mongo database. These functions are then referred in main server file for crud operations. But when i upgraded from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16 earlier this morning. it started giving me following error about these wrapper class functions.

```
TypeError: recipeData.getAllUsers is not a function
```

where getAllUsers is the function that has mongo queries being used in server class in the API's. and recipeData is the main folder with index.js(actual wrapper class) for that table. 
Folder Structure :

```
-recipe-data
---config.js
---index.js (Wrapper Class)
---package.js (Main class is set so whenever module is referred index.js is read)
---recipeCollection.js
-recipe-server
---routes
------index.js (this is server main)
---package.js
```

Following is the structure of wrapper class.
index.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
settings = require('./config.js');

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var fullMongoUrl = settings.mongoConfig.serverUrl +     settings.mongoConfig.database;
var exports = module.exports = {};

MongoClient.connect(fullMongoUrl)
    .then(function(db) {


 exports.delete_user = function(uuid) {
        console.log('@ Data delete user with uuid : ' + uuid);
        return userCollection.remove({ id: uuid }, 1).then(
            function(param) {
                console.log('Delete operation result : ' + JSON.stringify(param));
                return { status: 'success', result: param };
            },
            function(err) {
                return { status: 'failure', error: err };
            }
        );
    }

});
```

recipe-server : index.js (main file) as follows

```
 const recipeData = require("../../recipe-data");

 router.get('/users',(req,res){
     // some code
     >>> recipeData.getAllUsers().then(function(users) {
     Error : TypeError: recipeData.getAllUsers is not a function

 });
```

recipe-data -- > Package.js

```
{
  "name": "recipe-data",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Data for the recipe portion of our website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
         "seed": "node ./tasks/seed.js"
        },
  "author": "Phil Barresi",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
  "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
  "mongodb": "^2.2.10"
 }
}
```

recipe-server --> package.json

```
 {
  "name": "CS-554",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A small demo electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
             "start": "node app.js"
    },
  "productName": "CS-554",
  "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+https://github.com/Stevens-CS546/CS-554"
  },
  "keywords": [
   "quick",
   "start",
   "tutorial"
   ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/Stevens-CS546/CS-554/issues"
 },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Stevens-CS546/CS-554#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
  "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
  "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.12",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0"
 },
  "dependencies": {
  "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
  "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
  "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
  "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
  "mongodb": "^2.1.18",
  "node-redis-pubsub": "^0.9.0",
  "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
  "xss": "^0.2.13"
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your `package.json`, and did you re-run `npm install` after upgrading?

Comment: @Aurora0001 : i did updated the question